# VSCode use WSL ssh config and identity?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 10 and 11 to do all of my ssh stuff but I'd like to be able to use the wsl2 ssh config + identity + agent from wsl within my VSCode.

Saw some approaches with a seperate ssh.bat with one of the following contents

> C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe bash --login -c ssh %*
> C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe bash -ic 'ssh %*'
> C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh %*

With the ssh.bat beeing in the remote.SSH.Path.

The only error i could find was this but im pretty sure it worked like this before:

> [14:18:34.726] Got error from ssh: spawn
> "C:\Users<USER>\Documents\ssh.bat" ENOENT [14:18:34.727] The
> specified path "C:\Users<USER>\Documents\ssh.bat" is not a valid SSH
> binary

Nothing seemed to work. For some reason it does not use the wsl ssh.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Looking at the error message, is it possible you did not replace the `<USER>` placeholder with your actual username?

Answer (score 0):

The path

```
C:\Users<USER>\Documents\ssh.bat
```

is missing a backslash. It should be

```
C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\ssh.bat
```